# What is the purpose of the hypotenuse in the sobel edge detection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, edge-detection

I understand that you filter each pixel by a horizontal and vertical matrix that gives a horizontal and vertical gradient. The gradients represent the difference in color along their respective axis. That I understand. What I don't understand is how our final value is computed by squaring the gradients, adding them together, and then taking the square root of that. It must make sense somehow but I don't quite get it.

[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking, but by basic Euclidian geometry, given the diagram you show where `x` is the length of the "X gradient" line, and `y` is the length of the "Y gradient" line, then the length of the hypotenuse is `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` - the distance between the endpoints of the X and Y lines...

Comment: I don't understand why he is using the Pythagorean theorem. Why not average the differences? Like, what does the hypotenuse have to do with anything here? How does it even come into play?

Comment: So it's like, if there is a little x and y gradient the distance between them will be small (e.g. black). but if it is a big triangle the distance will be big (e.g. a color).

Comment: Consider the image as a surface -- image values correspond to the height of the surface (z coming out of the screen). The x gradient is telling you how much the surface slants in the x-direction. The y gradient similarly for the y direction. They are basically the two components of the surface orientation -- a vector in the x direction and a vector in the y. If you want to know the magnitude of the gradient you add them in quadrature. If you want to know the angle of the orientation, you take arctan(y/x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Together, the X and Y gradients make up a 2D vector, `(G_x,G_y)`.  You can think of this vector as an arrow based at the origin, which indicates the direction and the magnitude of the derivative of the image value at that point.  (More accurately, the Sobol filter uses the local pixel values to compute a finite-difference *approximation* of a derivative).

Vectors have both a direction and a magnitude; if you are only interested in the magnitude of this vector, you need to compute its length.  The Pythagorean theorem is how you compute this length:  `G = sqrt(G_x^2 + G_y^2)`.

---

The reason you want to use the vector length is that it is smoothly independent of the orientation of the edge.

If you try averaging or otherwise adding the absolute differences instead, your edge detector will be more sensitive to diagonal edges than to vertical or horizontal ones; alternatively, if you try taking the largest absolute value of the two vector elements, the reverse will be true.  Also, neither alternative is a smooth function of the input vector, which will cause "kinks" at vector orientations for which the functions aren't smooth.

If you are writing your own filter, it is easy to try this out.  A lack of smoothness and orientation-independence will show up as ugly artifacts in the result of your edge-detection filter.